# Where did the Register/install component go?

Tags: package, installation, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have developed a .bpl package with some components. I did this in C++ Builder XE7 and to install it I could just select "Install package" (or something similar) by right clicking on the .bpl project (in the project manager).

Now I have updated to C++ Builder Tokyo (10.2) and there is no alternative to install/uninstall the package from the project manager.

Has this function been moved/renamed? Do I really have to do it manually?

EDIT:
I solved it. For anyone having the same problem, It seems like the import from XE7 into 10.2 doesn't work that well. I opened it in 10.1 and there the install option became available. Then I opened that project in 10.2 and everything went fine now...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Win32 platform is selected when you want to install. Since IDE is a Win32 app, you can only install win32 components in it. The other platform targets just use components blindly. This causes other issues that Embarcadero has put on back-burner for way too long for example they have not done anything about [RSP-10456](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10456?filter=-2) since I reported it when XE8 was in beta.

Comment: I didn't even had the 64bit target installed. However, I got confirmed from Embarcadero that there is a problem with the Tokyo web installer. It was likely my Tokyo that wasn't correctly installed. For other reasons I downgraded back to Berlin. I don't think Tokyo is quite ready yet...

Comment: @MaxKielland I have ran into the same issue as well, but after contacting Embarcadero support, they sent me a link to the ISO that does not have the issue. You can download the ISO from [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30725).

Comment: Yes, that was the answer I got from Embarcadero, to use the ISO instead. But as I said, we downgraded for other reasons...